# Gradle build running hangs and does not finish - android studio 2.2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

The development environment is

Android Studio 2.2.3
jdk 8
Gradle integrated into Android Studio

As I wrote the build task is not completed. I can leave the computer on for hours does not change anything. Rarely, when I delete .gradle folder from the path of my user, the task is completed.

I tried to clean from the build menu
Invalidates the cache and restarts

Nothing changes .

On Ubuntu I have no such problems.

Comment: You said you don't have any problem on Ubuntu, so what kind of OS did you used? When is it occurred? Is it occurred every time you create a new project?

Comment: I use Last release of Windows 10 home edition. It's occurred for any project